# nodejs gm module script to split a big multipage tiff file in multiple single images

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

When executed from command line, invoking directly GraphicsMagick, the following instructions split  correctly a big tiff multipage image in several single image files. Now I need to find the right translation to make it work with the Node.js gm module ( 
http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/):

```
gm convert +adjoin -trim input.pdf PNG8:output%03d.png
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom arguments directly from nodejs.

**Example:**

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm().command('convert').in('+adjoin').in(filePath).write('image%02d.jpeg', function(err) {
   // something                
});
```

**Info:** https://github.com/aheckmann/gm